# Attempting to use SwiftUI preview, when I press 'Resume' to rebuild the view, Xcode is crashing

Tags: xcode, swiftui, resume

I am learning SwiftUI, I want to use SwiftUI preview, but when I press 'Resume' to rebuild the view, Xcode is crashing.

My os version is 10.15 beta and my Xcode version is 11.3 beta. Error is

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your Catalina. The current nonbeta version is macOS 10.15.1 (19B88). The current beta version is 10.15.2 beta 3 (19C46a). You are using 10.15 (19A526h), which is much too early to use with Xcode 11.3.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I upgrade the os version to 10.15.1 and the question is solved.